# NameValuePair and MultipartEntity

Tags: android, json, post, multipart

in my post request i previously used NameValuePair

```
Map<String, Object> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                data.put(SESSION, sessionId);
                data.put(MODULE_NAME, "POD_POD");

                try {

                    JSONArray nameValueArray = new JSONArray();
                   // signature_path_value.put("name", "uploadfile");
                    //signature_path_value.put("value", image_str);
                    //nameValueArray.put(signature_path_value);
                    customer_value.put("name", "signed_by");
                    customer_value.put("value", customer);
                    nameValueArray.put(customer_value);
                    order_time_value.put("name", "delivered_on");
                    order_time_value.put("value", order_time);
                    nameValueArray.put(order_time_value);
                    user_value.put("name", "driver_name");
                    user_value.put("value", user);
                    nameValueArray.put(user_value);

                    data.put(NAME_VALUE_LIST, nameValueArray);

                    String restData = org.json.simple.JSONValue.toJSONString(data);

                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost req = new HttpPost(rest_url);
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(METHOD, SET_ENTRY));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(INPUT_TYPE, JSON));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(RESPONSE_TYPE, JSON));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(REST_DATA, restData));
                    req.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Send POST request
                    httpClient.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
                    HttpResponse res = httpClient.execute(req);
```

but now i use MultiPartEntity to upload Image to server..i know using 'myEntity.addPart()' in can add String values to multipartentity.but how can i add these lines to multiPartEntity

```
JSONArray nameValueArray = new JSONArray();
                       // signature_path_value.put("name", "uploadfile");
                        //signature_path_value.put("value", image_str);
                        //nameValueArray.put(signature_path_value);
                        customer_value.put("name", "signed_by");
                        customer_value.put("value", customer);
                        nameValueArray.put(customer_value);
                        order_time_value.put("name", "delivered_on");
                        order_time_value.put("value", order_time);
                        nameValueArray.put(order_time_value);
                        user_value.put("name", "driver_name");
                        user_value.put("value", user);
                        nameValueArray.put(user_value);

data.put(NAME_VALUE_LIST, nameValueArray);

                    String restData = org.json.simple.JSONValue.toJSONString(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I given sample code for how to use `MultipartEntity` with string and file data.

```
        MultipartEntity mEntity = new MultipartEntity();

        //For String data 

        mEntity.addPart("key1", new StringBody("value1"));
        mEntity.addPart("key2", new StringBody("value2"));
        mEntity.addPart("key3", new StringBody("value3"));


        //For File data
        mEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody("file_path"));
        req.setEntity(mEntity);
```

in you case try below code.

```
        mEntity.addPart(METHOD, new StringBody(SET_ENTRY));
        mEntity.addPart(INPUT_TYPE, new StringBody(JSON));
        mEntity.addPart(RESPONSE_TYPE, new StringBody(JSON));
        mEntity.addPart(REST_DATA, new StringBody(restData));
```

Comment: Thank you..but in Namevaluepair i used 'data.put(NAME_VALUE_LIST, nameValueArray);' and the add data to namevaluepair array like this 'nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(REST_DATA, restData));' how can i do like tis n multipartentity because Service want to receive data in correct order

Comment: @Sameera ohhh so you are creating JSON data and sending.. I just given sample code. you can modify it.

Comment: yes.i did many research about to add json data to multipart entity..but i didnt find any example.can you give little ex. to how to add json data to multipart entity?

Comment: Thank you. in your 'restData' String has my JSON values ?

Comment: another one question :D how can i add my file_path as json data or should i add it directly to mEntity

Comment: @Sameera :D you can directly add, no need to create JSON, and its also depend on server side, how web code handling file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75702/discussion-between-sameera-and-capdroid).